# Получение значений через обратные связи

Tags: python, django

Есть модель:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    Content = models.TextField()
    Dialog = models.ForeignKey(
        Dialogue, 
        related_name='messages', 
        related_query_name="messages")
```

И модель Dialogue - диалог, который содержит множество сообщений. пускай

```
class Dialogue(models.Model):
    pass
```

Я хочу сделать что-то подобное (код нерабочий, но, как мне кажется, вполне отражающий суть):

```
Dialogue.objects.filter(messages__count__gt=0).annotate(message__last)
```

то есть я хочу нечто вроде агрегации последнего сообщения диалога вместе с полученным значением этого диалога.

Знаю, что нечто подобное могу сделать через select_related, но тогда в выборку попадет куча лишних сообщений, и select_related не гибок, не позволяет ограничивать выборку по количеству (либо я не нашел как это делать)

Comment: Какую версию django используете?

Comment: @avtomato, 1.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из возможных вариантов, как раз появившийся в версии 1.11, использование [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions):

Определяем подзапрос в котором получаем необходимый `Message`:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

subquery = (
    Message
    .objects
    .filter(Dialog=OuterRef('pk'))
    .order_by('-id')
    .values('Content')[:1]
)
```

Для примера я использовал `id`, т.е. в моем случае последним сообщением считается имеющие наибольшее значение `id`. Вам необходимо заменить на нужный параметр.

Далее аннотируем каждый `Dialogue` содержим атрибута `Content` модели `Message` и убираем диалоги в которых нет сообщений:

```
Dialogue.objects.annotate(message__last=Subquery(subquery)).filter(message__last__isnull=False)
```

Comment: здОрово! Это действительно что-то новое для меня!

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, что делает OuterRef. Получается, он ничего не фильтрует в первом фильтре? А просто "подтягивает" поле Content к общему запросу через primarykey?

Comment: В целом да, это должно быть ссылкой на существующее поле в внешнем запросе, необязательно `pk`. В сыром SQL это будет выглядеть как условие, примерно так: `WHERE U0."Dialog_id" = ("dialogue"."id")`, где U0 алиас для подзапроса.